# Adding a function to tkinter menu to run ONLY if x != None

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I would like to have a menu bar on my GUI. In this menu bar I want there to be 1 label, when this label is click, the value of `file_data_for_processing` should be checked. Then, depending if it's true or not, 1 of 2 functions will run. I would like to check this in the same statement that I call the function.

The code I got so far:

```
self.menu_main_top_evaluation.add_command(label=self.test_me,
    command=lambda: guif.run_test(self.test_me, self.file_data_for_processing))
```

As it is right now, I would have to do a third function that would first check the value of `file_data_for_processing` then, depending on the outcome, I would have to choose which function to call.

Comment: What's the point in cramming all of that code into a lambda? Your code will be easier to maintain and easier to debug if the menu item calls a simple command, and then put all of your logic in that command. The use of lambda here does nothing but make the code harder to understand.

Comment: @BryanOakley Okay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is with a standard function. lambda is really only useful when you must pass arguments to a function, which you don't need to do here. Otherwise, lambda just makes the card harder to write, harder to understand, and harder to debug. For me, personally, my rule of thumb is to never use lambda until I absolutely must use lambda (or its equivalent, such as `functools.partial`).

First and foremost, code needs to be clear and easy to read. It is read way more often than it is written or modified, so unless there is a compelling reason to do otherwise you should optimize for readability.

I would write the code like this:

```
class Something(...):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.menu_main_top_evaluation.add_command(
            label=self.test_me, command=self._test_me
        )
        ...

    def _test_me(self):
        if self.file_data_for_processing:
            do_something()
        else:
            do_something_else()
```

Note: the choice of using a `_` prefix is purely for illustrative purposes. A leading underscore helps document that this is a function that is private to the class, but you can use any name you want of course. It's a good idea to come up with a naming convention that means something to you, so that it's easy to remember which functions are associated with which menu items.